# Error in t.default(x) : argument is not a matrix

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to see what people's willingness to pay is for either nuclear or wind energy (far away or local) through a stated choice preference. I used the multinomial logit model, however when estimating the discreet choice for the different scenarios I keep getting  an error:

```
Error in t.default(x) : argument is not a matrix
```

While gmnl gives this error, mixl seems to be working fine
Code:

```
install.packages("gmnl")
install.packages("mlogit") 
library("gmnl") # Load gmnl package
library("mlogit") # Load mlogit package
library(readxl)
Example_data <- read_excel("Example data.xlsx")
View(Example_data)
data <- as.data.frame(Example_data)
df01 <- mlogit.data(data,
                    id.var = "id",
                    choice = "Choice",
                    varying = 3:17,     
                    shape = "wide",
                    sep = "")

lc <- gmnl(Choice ~ MODE + DWELLING + SIZE + COST + DISTANCE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 , 
           data = df01,
           model = 'lc', 
           Q = 3, 
           panel = TRUE,
           method = "bhhh")
```

It could be that there is something wrong with my data. However, when comparing previous works from other people my data is setup in a similar way and I cannot run their calculations either.
From what I have seen with earlier posts, it could also be a package problem. But what can I do to fix it or continue if that is the case.

The picture below shows an example of the data for 2 individuals, which consists of 15 scenarios with 3 options to choose from.
[Example_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0fWi.png)